# Regression Testing: How do I interpret whether or not my null hypothesis overlaps with my confidence interval?

Tags: regression

I have a fairly simple question.

I'm performing a hypothesis test against a linear regression (where my regression was run within Excel against a sample).

My null hypothesis is: B1 <= -6000

Excel tells me that the Upper and Lower Limit of B1's confidence interval is: [-4000, -1000].

I know from my professor that in this case, because my null hypothesis DOES overlap with my confidence interval then I cannot reject the null hypothesis.

My question here is quite simple: I don't understand how one would come to the conclusion that B1 <= -6000 DOES overlap with [-4000, -1000]. No matter how I read this, in my brain, there is no overlap. This clearly means that I'm reading it incorrectly.

Can someone help me understand how to interpret this particular null hypothesis against this confidence interval so that I can come to the correct conclusion?

Comment: You are correct that a confidence interval of $(-4000,-1000)$ is evidence against the value being $-6000$ or lower. Are you sure you didn’t make a typo?

Comment: @filmnut: As Dave mentioned, do you mean -10000 and not -1000 ?

Comment: Perhaps your professor was mistaken ?

Comment: Thanks for these comments, as they at least tell me that I'm not going crazy. :) 

Perhaps my professor had a typo in his email to me, wherein he meant to say -10000 and not -1000. I'll double-check with him.